# how to dual boot the ubuntu and windows 7 again?(after install ubuntu)

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot

i have problem with dual booting windows and ubuntu...
i had windows 7 then i installed ubuntu 12.4. 
ubuntu installed side by side windows and everything worked just fine..

then i decide to install ubuntu 12.10. i didn't upgrade it from update manager . i reinstalled it from boot.and in the installation i chose (something else)...and i deleted swap and root and boot partition and recreate all of it. after install, windows does not come up. i dont know how bring it up.
is there software like easy bcd for ubuntu? i want my windows 7 back.i want both of them side by side like before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have not deleted or somehow damaged your Windows partition, you should be able to see Windows 7 again on your Grub menu if you install and run the famous **Boot-Repair** utility:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
boot-repair
```